# Use proxy for remote connection

Tags: networking, proxy, tor

I want to connect to a remote computer using PuTTY, i.e. client and server; How do I setup my proxy and port forwarding settings?

And I'm using Tor for all my network, but something went wrong:

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/4v041i/5]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First half of this answer (quoted parts) is taken from [TorifyHOWTO Wiki page](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/Putty), updated by me to be more current, and I have reconstructed images that have broken links there according to their description in the how-to. No copyright infringement intended.

> Putty is a free application suite for Windows that provides such tools
>   as Telnet, SSH and SCP, along with a very good xterm emulator. It's
>   written and maintained by Tatham and can be downloaded via links on
>   its homepage at http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/.
>
> The first application to Torify is Putty itself. This is a combined
>   Telnet/SSH client. When started, you are presented with a Session
>   configuration screen (shown below).

[image: PuTTY Session]

> This screen is used to select the host you wish to connect with, the
>   preferred port and the connection type, (`Raw`, `Telnet`, `Rlogin`, `SSH`, `Serial`). It
>   also enables a session configuration to be saved and retrieved. For
>   this reason, I suggest configuring the other session tabs first and
>   then returning to this one in order to save the configuration.
>
> Only one other tab requires configuration specifically for Tor, and
>   that's the Proxy tab (shown below).

[image: PuTTY Proxy]

> The above image shows the settings exactly as they should be set for
>   usage with Tor. Pay particular attention to the "Do DNS lookup at
>   proxy end:" option. If this is set to Off or Auto, then DNS will leak
>   information about what services are being used.
>
> That's it for Putty. Return to the Session tab and save the
>   configuration if desired.

For PuTTY command line tools, please refer to the [source how-to Wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/Putty).

As for port-forwarding, there is nothing in particular that you'd need to set up for that on your router, since your proxy will be the local Tor's Vidalia listening on `localhost` port you configure and it will be forwarding requests through the TCP connection using standard HTTP ports. Make sure you have Vidalia properly configured, running and connected to Tor network, and especially pay attention to Vidalia's local port that should match the one used in your PuTTY proxy configuration. This setting can be found in `Settings -> Advanced -> Tor Control` in the Vidalia Control Panel (see images below).

[image: Vidalia Control Panel]

[image: Vidalia Advanced Settings]